# Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\frac{\ln{n}}{n-\ln{n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

**Problem_**

> Evaluate $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\left[\frac{\ln{n}}{n-\ln{n}}\right]$$

I separated the given fraction into two fractions:
$$\frac{1}{n}\left[\frac{\ln{n}}{n-\ln{n}}\right]=\frac{1}{n-\ln{n}}-\frac{1}{n}$$

But, the terms are not erased by others. Then, how can I find out the values of each series? Actually, it is impossible to find out the sum of each series since both them diverge:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n-\ln{n}}>\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}>\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^n\frac{1}{2^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty1=(diverge)$$So the new idea should be established. Could you please suggest me other methods? Thanks.

[**EDIT**] I've also taken account of Riemann Sum, but I still don't know how to apply it.

Comment: Do you want the exact value of this series?

Comment: Yes, sir. Is it quite hard to have the exact value?

Comment: Well, I don't know right now :)